# Rule based boosting at the field level

Tags: solr, content-search, boosting

We are using `Sitecore 9.1`, `Solr 7.7` and are NOT using `SXA`.
I tried creating a `boosting rule` and associated the rule with the template.
The rule is as below:

```
where the page title field contains bills
adjust boost by 2
```

I rebuilt the indexes but it doesn't affect the results.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official documentation states that this is broken.

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/search-result-boosting.html

> Search result boosting works in Solr version 6.6 or earlier, but Solr changed the implementation in Solr 7, and later versions. Therefore, search result boosting is broken in Sitecore 9.1, 9.2, and 9.3.

> In SItecore 10, and later, item-level boosting works again, but field-level boosting does not. Sitecore stores the item boosting factor in a separate field in the Solr index ((__boost : pfloat). Sitecore uses the value in this field for boosting.